# Loading multiple iframes without reloading parent page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have multiple iframes that I'm loading on a page my goal is to load those iframes immediately the parent page has finished loading, however I don't want the parent page to reload while I'm loading the iframes. What I have tried to do is to add an event listener for when the parent page window has completed loading, then go ahead and append the iframe to the page. However this is causing the parent page to reload. Reference to the code is below. Also just to add the iframe is from a different domain as the parent page.

```js
const iFrameResize = (obj) => { console.log(obj) }
const style = "Bla";
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('hey..........')
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
  iframe.src = "https://iframe.domain.com"
  iframe.width = "100%"
  iframe.frameBorder = "0"
  iframe.id = "iframe-1"
  iframe.onload = function onloadHandler(e) {
    var iframe = e.target
    var iframeId = '#' + iframe.id
    iFrameResize({
      log: true
    }, iframeId)
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(style, "*");
  }
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will reload the parent

Comment: What is the usecase for iframes? You know you can just load a div with a file from same domain using ajax?

Comment: Why would iframe.onload bubble to window.onload?

Comment: Do you see two hey.... here?

Comment: @Teemu is my answer safer then?

Comment: @Teemu what would be your suggestion to prevent that behaviour

Comment: @oma0256 Try my code

Comment: @mplungjan Not sure, can't test it with real iframes just now. Perhaps setting `e.stopPropagation()` in the iframe loader makes the trick? Or there really is something in OP's code, which makes the parent to reload, but that's not shown in the example.

Comment: @mplungjan let me try your code. Thank you.

Comment: @Teemu let me try your suggestion as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Teemu the suggestion didn't work, still performs the same behaviour

Comment: Also just to add the iframe is from a different domain as the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true that window.onload bubbles, perhaps try this

```js
const iFrameResize = (obj,sel) => {
  console.log(obj,sel)
  document.querySelector(sel).style.display="block";
}
const style = "Bla";

function onloadHandler(e) {
  const iFrame = e.target;
  console.log(iFrame.src)
  const iframeSelector = '#' + iFrame.id
  iFrameResize({
    log: true
  }, iframeSelector)
  iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(style, "*");
}

window.addEventListener("load", e => {
  console.log(e.target.location.href)
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
  iframe.width = "100%"
  iframe.frameBorder = "0"
  iframe.style.display="none";
  iframe.id = "iframe-"+document.querySelectorAll("iframe").length;
  iframe.addEventListener("load", onloadHandler);
  iframe.src = "https://google.com/search?q="+iframe.id
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
})
```

Comment: This didn't work, still performs the same behaviour

Comment: So why does the page not reload here?

Comment: It's reloading, the goal if for the page not reload once the iframe is appended to the parent page.

Comment: If it was reloading you would see `https://stacksnippets.net/js` twice

Comment: Ohh.. sorry about that confusion, what happens is once the parent page loads instead of it terminating it continues to load in order to display the iframe.
Isn't it possible for the parent page to load completely first then start loading the iframe without the main page showing that it's loading.

Comment: Issue still persists. Tested out without adding the iframe and the page will load fast, however while adding the iframe it will load the page and continue loading the iframe as well instead of doing the loading of the iframe in the background without showing that the parent is still loading.

Comment: "The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading."

Comment: Is their any other event that can be used for this use case?
Is their a way forward such that we can prevent increasing the load time? Because the issue is they are going to be multiple iframes on the page.

Comment: The issue is likely you have something ELSE on the page that loads after the page has loaded. If you have another load even that starts inserting dynamic content you will need to add your iframe loading to the end of that  code